# ¿Es posible identificar cuando se hace una llamada a una pagina por un navegador o por api?

Tags: php, api, restful

Estoy armando un frame para API RESt y quiero ver si es posible de realizar esta idea.
El plan es identificar los ingresos al link para los llamados, si se hace una entrada al link por el navegador, se redireccionaria a otra pagina X y que solo sea posible hacer uso de la API REST desde una llamada api como tal.

Tengo hasta el momento la idea de que sea algo a hacerse desde el htaccess o a identificar con PHP.

Como plan 2 igual podria hacer que si no existen los contextos basicos como el Authetication, redireccionar, pero quiero ver si es posible esta opcion previa.

Comment: Revisando los Headers?

Comment: Claro, eso podria hacerlo a nivel de php, pero que otros metodos pueden haber?

Comment: Identificando una cookie en PHP, o en la redirección en htaccess agregar un parámetro adicional.